# Linq-Sql IQueryable<T> and chaining OR operations

Tags: linq-to-sql, iqueryable, conditional-operator

I'm trying to simulate:

WHERE x.IsActive = true OR x.Id = 5

The following causes 'AND' to be used... how do I simulate an 'OR' condition with IQueryable (qry) and my nullable int, given that other filtering might be involved as with the IsActive filter here?

```
            if (onlyActiveItems) //bool
            {
                qry = qry.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
            }

            if (whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId.HasValue) //int?
            {
                qry = qry.Where(x => x.Id == whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId.Value);
            }
```

I have considered union but its seems the answer to this should be much simpler.

---

This is one solution which gets around the problem I get with "Nullable object must have a value" when trying the combined all in one answer.  What causes the nullable to be evaluated when it is null otherwise?

```
            if (whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId.HasValue)
            {
                qry = qry.Where(x => (!onlyActiveItems || (onlyActiveItems && x.IsActive)) || x.Id == whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                qry = qry.Where(x => (!onlyActiveItems || (onlyActiveItems && x.IsActive)));
            }
```

It seems also in some cases the use of the nullable's .Value property makes a difference as seen in another question of mine here [Linq to SQL Int16 Gets Converted as Int32 In SQL Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634992/linq-to-sql-int16-gets-converted-as-int32-in-sql-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
qry = qry.Where(x => (onlyActiveItems
                      ? x.IsActive
                      : false) ||
                     (whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId.HasValue
                      ? x.Id == whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId
                      : false) ||
                     (!onlyActiveItems && !whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId.HasValue));
```

Note that we're comparing an `int?` to an `int`, not two `int`s.

I am assuming here that the point of the query is to filter out if certain conditions are met.

- If `onlyActiveItems` is true, it verifies whether the IsActive field is true
- If `whenSpecifiedMustIncludeRecordWithThisId.HasValue` is true it verifies whether the value matches the Id field
- If both are true it will logically OR the conditions
- If both are false all records are displayed (if this is not the intent, you can remove the last condition)

Comment: I'm getting "Nullable object must have a value" in the case when the int? is null.

Comment: Give this revised solution a try

Comment: Still no luck, I'm thinking maybe something else may be causing that but its very unusual

Comment: Sorry had a bit of the logic backwards, this should work as expected.

Comment: I have made some adjustments to logically OR the conditions if both are true.

Comment: That did the trick! Changed "onlyActiveItems ? x.IsActive : true" instead of false, because the bool filters only when true.

Answer (score 0):

When working with "int?" I usually compare them using object.Equals(i1, i2), for example

```
from r in cxt.table
where object.Equals(r.column, nullableInt)
select r
```

This avoids all nullable issues.